# Sharepoint 2010 ECMAScript Object Model: Insert, Update, Delete

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

is it possible to add a new Item to a list / delete it / update it via ECMAScript Object Model? All I've found is about reading items. Are all the CRUD operations supported? If so, can you provide me with a link to the documentation explaining it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-use-ecmascript-to.html